# How to add a WHERE condition in a Lucene query

Tags: java, spring-boot, lucene

I have the following code for searching a "Keyword" in the student_table using Lucene query.

```
public List search(String search, LONG studentCity) {
   FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
   QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Spot.class).get();
   Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword().fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(1).withPrefixLength(1).onFields("name", "description", "address").matching(search).createQuery();
```

I got all the rows in the student_table that contain the "Keyword", but I need to add a condition such:" **where student_table.city_id= studentCity**"

So I can restrict the result of the query by the City Id.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To add the city_id=studentCity contition, you're going to need a TermQuery (and the appropiate field type when you index your document)
After that you'll have to wrap your fuzzy query and the TermQuery in a BooleanQuery with both occurrence conditions set to MUST.

That'll be the query you pass to your IndexReader / IndexSearcher.

Hope that helps!

Comment: an example would help even more